# TableView drag & drop to empty table

Tags: javafx

I have two TableViews, and I drag & drop items between them. Unfortunately, it seems that neither `setOnDragOver` or `setOnDragDropped` are never triggered if the target table has no items. Is there a way to make them trigger somehow? Only thing that comes to my mind is to have some kind of empty/dummy cell instead of a completely empty table. But I find this a bit hacky and would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Table, of course, can accept drag & drop events itself, and they do trigger for empty tables. I was thinking in TableRows only, and I feel stupid now!